# When is the skeleton object created in RMI?

Tags: java, rmi

In books, I read that when we compile implementation class with rmic, it creates two objects: stub and skeleton. But when I compile server side implementation class it only creates a stub object file. The code is:

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;

public class ServerImp extends UnicastRemoteObject implements testRmi
{
    ServerImp() throws RemoteException
    {
    }

    public void getText(String gt) throws RemoteException
    {
        System.out.println(gt);
    }
}
```

Can somebody tell me when the skeleton file is created?

Comment: you don't need rmic, stubs, or skeletons anymore.  find a java book updated within the last 10 years or so.

Comment: If the book talks about skeletons, it's probably at least 15 years old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since rmic 1.2 onwards, Java doesn't generate skeleton class any more. New JRMP protocol supported for RMI has got rid of the use of skeleton files.

> A skeleton for a remote object is a JRMP protocol server-side entity
>   that has a method that dispatches calls to the actual remote object
>   implementation.

Comment: More precisely, skeletons aren't used by default, but the stub infrastructure is all still there, causing continual confusion. :-)

Comment: @StuartMarks Correct. The infrastructure is still there to support the Registry, which still uses it, for compatibility reasons. The Stub created by LocateRegistry.getRegistry() is still a 1.1 stub which speaks the skeleton protocol.

Comment: I have the proxy pattern example in Head first design patterns book (with Java 6). It keeps talking about Skeleton classes. But, only the stub is generated with rmic & skeleton class is not generated. Will the code work without the skeleton ?

Answer (score 3):

Skeletons were replaced by general server-side dispatch code in JDK 1.2 (released 1998). Statically generated stubs were replaced by dynamic proxies in JDK 5 (released 2004). There is no longer need to use `rmic` to generate stubs for running RMI over JRMP. (Note however that `rmic` is still necessary for using IIOP.)

I'm astounded by the number of questions on stackoverflow asking about `rmic`, stubs, and skeletons. People must be looking at very old books and very out-of-date web tutorials. It would be helpful if links were posted to some of these so that the authors can be contacted to update or remove the obsolete information.

Maybe the old stub support should be deprecated. That might help avoid the confusion.

---

Edit: Oh, I guess maybe I should answer the question too. :-)

Edit2: removed erroneous statement about `UnicastRemoteObject` constructor.

Statically generated skeletons are no longer necessary. In your code above, your remote object extends `UnicastRemoteObject`. When your object is constructed, the `UnicastRemoteObject` constructor is called. This hooks up the object to the RMI internal infrastructure that handles socket listening and remote method dispatch. In other words, it "exports" the object.

Comment: I have the proxy pattern example in Head first design patterns book (with Java 6). It keeps talking about Skeleton classes. But, only the stub is generated with rmic & skeleton class is not generated. Will the code work without the skeleton ?